# Interpretation of proof of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure as a $\sup$ over compact subsets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

**The following is part of a theorem and proof in Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications:***

Let $\mu$ be a complete Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $\mathbb{R}$ associated to the increasing right continuous function $F$, and denote by $\mathcal{M}_{\mu}$ the domain of $\mu$.

If $E \in \mathcal{M}_{\mu}$, and if $E$ is bounded, then
\begin{equation}
\mu(E) = \sup \left\{ \mu(K): K \subset E \text{ and $K$ is compact} \right\}
\end{equation}

**Proof:**

If $E$ is closed then $E$ is compact and the equality is obvious. Otherwise, given $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose an open $U$ such that $\bar{E}\setminus E \subset U$ such that $\mu(U) \leq \mu(\bar{E}\setminus E) + \epsilon$. Let $K=\bar{E} \setminus U$. Then $K$ is compact and $K \subset E$, and

\begin{align}
\mu(K) &= \mu(E)  - \mu (E \cap U)\\
&=\mu(E) - \left[ \mu(U) - \mu(U\setminus E) \right]\\
&\geq \mu(E) - \mu(U) + \mu(\bar{E} \setminus E)\\
&\geq \mu(E) - \epsilon\\
\end{align}

This concludes the proof.

However, I cannot understand either the first or second equality above (although I feel the answer must be obvious).

How do we get that $\mu(K) = \mu(E)  - \mu (E \cap U)$?

How do we get that $\mu(K)= \mu(E) - \left[ \mu(U) - \mu(U\setminus E) \right]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, notice that $E=K\cup(E\cap U)$ is a disjoint union.

For the second, notice that $U=(E\cap U)\cup (U\setminus E)$ is a disjoint union.

All sets are measurable, so the measure is additive.